# How do I stop Ubuntu One from syncing when I login?

Tags: ubuntu-one, startup

how do I stop ubuntu one from syncing on start up of computer

Answer (score 5):

Just uncheck "Ubuntu One" in menu System -> Preferences -> Start applications
You then have to start manually, when you want to use it.

[image]